# Drawing a CGPDFDocumentRef

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, uiview, core-graphics

I'm trying to draw a CGPDFDocumentRef on an UIView. Everything works just fine, excepting by the fact that the PDF is being drew too small on the view. I'm not sure why it's happening. I've tried changing the values on CGContextScaleCTM() and CGContextTranslateCTM(). I also tried using other boxes instead of kCGPDFCropBox. I've seen a lot of people using the same code and everything works for them. Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Not even Apple's documentation had an answer for my question.

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGPDFPageRef pg = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, page);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGAffineTransform PDFTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(pg, kCGPDFCropBox, self.bounds, 0, true);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, PDFTransform);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pg);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot so we can see what "too small" means?

Comment: Edited my post and included the image.

Comment: Can you post a link to download the PDF file? I need to see the values for cropbox and mediabox and perform some tests before I can give you an answer.

Comment: Here is [link with the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641068/in-ios-using-cgpdfdocumentref-why-is-my-pdf-showing-big-margins-and-not-the-wh) Try it out! It solved my issue! Best of Luck!

Comment: Here is [link with the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641068/in-ios-using-cgpdfdocumentref-why-is-my-pdf-showing-big-margins-and-not-the-wh) Try it out! It solved my issue! Best of Luck!